# Return value as variable from Mongoose find query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am quite new to this and so I have looked at other answers and can't get my head around them.

What I want to do:

When posting from my site I want to add a new document to my database. Document looks like this:

```
 const weightSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    weight: {
   type: Number
   },
   date: String,
   change: Number
  });
```

The 'change' key should take the current weight value just posted (entered by user) and subtract it from the previous weight value. Ie calculate weight change.

I am able to get the console to log the number using this:

```
Weight.find(function(err, foundWeights){
 if (err) {
  console.log(err)
 } else {
    if (foundWeights.length-1 === 0) {
      console.log(0)
   } else {
      const previousWeight = foundWeights[foundWeights.length-1].weight;
      const changeInWeight = weightInLbs - previousWeight;
      console.log(changeInWeight);
 }}});
```

However I can't access the values which are currently console logged outside of the query. Any help would be great!

Really what I want is to make:

```
const resultingWeightChange = Weight.find(function..... etc)
```